# Firebase retrieve multiple child from realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a list of paragraphs in my firebase realtime database

[image]

And I want to randomly retrieve multiple of them based on random array values like

> const x = [0, 2, 5].

I retrieve data with get()

```
const parasnapshot0 = await get(child(dbRef, `paragraphs/${x[0]}`));
const parasnapshot1 = await get(child(dbRef, `paragraphs/${x[1]}`));
const parasnapshot2 = await get(child(dbRef, `paragraphs/${x[2]}`));
```

The problem with this is it won't scale well and the query made to firebase would hog on the network.
Is there a way to make 1 query and retrieve a list/json of the items I need? Something like:

```
const parasnapshot2 = await get(child(dbRef, `paragraphs/${x[0]},${x[1]},${x[2]}`));
```

Comment: "The problem with this is it won't scale well and the query made to firebase would hog on the network" It actually doesn't, as Firebase pipelines the requests over a single web socket connection. I recommend checking the network panel of your browser's debugging tools, and my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: Thanks I didn't actually know about the pipelining